# Proper setup for firebase app-check in Angular (@angular/fire)

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire, firebase-app-check

Angular version: 15.2.9
AngularFire version: 7.5.0

Here is my code:

(app.module.ts)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { LayoutModule } from '@angular/cdk/layout' ;
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { getApp, initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { ReCaptchaV3Provider, initializeAppCheck, provideAppCheck } from '@angular/fire/app-check' ;
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { provideAuth,getAuth, connectAuthEmulator } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { provideFirestore,getFirestore, Firestore, initializeFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideAppCheck( () => initializeAppCheck(undefined, {
      provider: new ReCaptchaV3Provider(environment.recaptchaV3SiteKey),
      isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true
    })),
    provideAuth(() => {
      const auth = getAuth() ;
      if (environment.useEmulators){
        connectAuthEmulator(auth, 'http://localhost:9099', {
          disableWarnings: true
        }) ;
      }

      return auth ;
    }),
    provideFirestore(() => {
      let firestore: Firestore ;
      if (environment.useEmulators){
        firestore = initializeFirestore(getApp(), {
          experimentalForceLongPolling: true
        }) ;
      }
      else{
        firestore = getFirestore() ;
      }

      return firestore ;
    }),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    LayoutModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

after this in my login component:

[image: login.component.ts]

Which gives following error log in development mode:

[image: development log]

I added the given debug token in app-check console in firebase. After that also I'm getting 403 error with response as:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Invalid API key for project ID: demo-project",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

when checking the result for `console.log(this.appcheck)` it give my app credentials with `demo-project` as my projectId. But when i build my app for production it gives my firebase project id with different debug token and different 403 response with message "App attest failed".

I've checked numerous guides and other questions on stackoverflow but still confused about how to setup properly for local and production development.

**Edit 1**: Added screenshot for production mode. Debug token is different and now `this.appcheck` is giving correct projectId instead of `demo-project` when using ng serve.

[image: production mode]

also added screenshot of 403 response.

[image: 403 production error response]

**Edit 2**: When setting up firestore and auth emulators in some guides they told to change the projectId to `demo-*`. So, in my dev enironment.ts I changed back my project id. Now I'm getting app-check token back. In dev mode it's ok to show the debug token but in production it's still showing the above production error with different debug id with attestation failed. How to fix this issue ?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot for when it fails in production?

Comment: @AlexanderN. updated you can check

Comment: You forgot to turn off debug mode in production and the debug key is different. Did you add that new debug key to the console?

Comment: How to turn off debug mode ? As far i remember  i didn't add that `self.FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN`  in my build. The debug token given in production I haven't added it in console I'll add that update here again !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking 3 days to finally fix this problem. I check the dev server source and in the app check init function it checks the global value `FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN` if it's string or set to true. Then it will show the log with debug token otherwise it will generate new one.

So, answer is to set as false for production verison and to debug token saved in firebase console for development version.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (!environment.production){
      self.FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN = environment.debugToken ;
    }
    else{
      self.FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN = environment.debugToken ;
    }
  }
}
```

Production console log:

[image: production console log]

Also, the issue with 403 on production solved after selecting disable cache in network tab and refreshing the production page. I think browser was using an older version where i didn't changed the projectId as well as didn't set DEBUG TOKEN to false.